# How to conbine two diffrence label's number to a new label?

Tags: c#, webforms

I need to calculate the Lb1SumF plus Lb2SumF equal Lb3SumF.
I ran it, and somehow the label3 does not display the expected result.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFpSb.jpg) is a screenshot from result.

Here is my code.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TX1.TabIndex=0;
}

private void TX1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        int sumF;
        sumF = Convert.ToInt32(Lb1PriceF.Text) * Convert.ToInt32(TX1.Text);
        Lb1SumF.Text = Convert.ToString(sumF); //Label1 sum

    }

    catch
    {
        Lb1SumF.Text = "0";
    }
}

private void TX2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        int sumF;
        sumF = Convert.ToInt32(Lb2PriceF.Text) * Convert.ToInt32(TX2.Text);
        Lb2SumF.Text = Convert.ToString(sumF); //Label2 sum

    }

    catch
    {
        Lb2SumF.Text = "0";
    }
}

private void Lb3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       int i = Convert.ToInt32(Lb1SumF.Text);
       int j = Convert.ToInt32(Lb2SumF.Text);
       Lb3.Text = Convert.ToString(i+j); // Label3 sum 
}
```

Comment: what is `Lb3` is it a textbox or a label?

Comment: `Lb3_TextChanged` might never be invoked as you are not changing the text of the label. I would rather suggest to change it to a private method and not an event handler. Let's say you name it to `UpdateSum()` where your first line should be checking `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Lb1SumF.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Lb2SumF.Text)` after which you can keep the existing code. Call the `UpdateSum()` method in `TX1_TextChanged` and `TX2_TextChanged`

Comment: I have added the code reflecting my comment as well

Answer (score 1):

`Lb3_TextChanged` might never be invoked as you are not changing the text of the label. I would suggest to change it to a private method and not an event handler. Here is what the code could be like:

```
    private void TX1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            int sumF;
            sumF = Convert.ToInt32(Lb1PriceF.Text) * Convert.ToInt32(TX1.Text);
            Lb1SumF.Text = Convert.ToString(sumF); //Label1 sum

            // Call to update sum
            UpdateSum();
        }
        catch
        {
            Lb1SumF.Text = "0";
        }
    }

    private void TX2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            int sumF;
            sumF = Convert.ToInt32(Lb2PriceF.Text) * Convert.ToInt32(TX2.Text);
            Lb2SumF.Text = Convert.ToString(sumF); //Label2 sum

            // Call to update sum
            UpdateSum();
        }
        catch
        {
            Lb2SumF.Text = "0";
        }
    }

    // private void Lb3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    private void UpdateSum()
    {
           int sum = 0;

           if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Lb1SumF.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Lb2SumF.Text))
           {
              sum = Convert.ToInt32(Lb1SumF.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(Lb2SumF.Text);
           }

           Lb3.Text = Convert.ToString(sum);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace you code with this it will work, you are using * operator where you have to use + operator, I have commented that lines in your code and replaced it for better understanding. 
Happy Coding

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp8
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private void Lb1SumF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TX1.TabIndex=0;
        }

        private void label4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void TX1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                int sumF; 
                //sumF = Convert.ToInt32(Lb1PriceF.Text) * Convert.ToInt32(TX1.Text); // You were doing wrong here , you were multiplying these values
                sumF = Convert.ToInt32(Lb1PriceF.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(TX1.Text);
                Lb1SumF.Text = Convert.ToString(sumF); //Label1 sum
            }
            catch
            {
                Lb1SumF.Text = "0";
            }
        }

        private void TX2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                int sumF;
                //sumF = Convert.ToInt32(Lb2PriceF.Text) * Convert.ToInt32(TX2.Text); //you are doing it wrong here , you are multiplying
                sumF = Convert.ToInt32(Lb2PriceF.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(TX2.Text);
                Lb2SumF.Text = Convert.ToString(sumF); //Label2 sum
            }
            catch
            {
                Lb2SumF.Text = "0";
            }
        }

        private void Lb3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
               int i = Convert.ToInt32(Lb1SumF.Text);
               int j = Convert.ToInt32(Lb2SumF.Text);
               Lb3.Text = Convert.ToString(i+j); // Label3 sum 
        }

        private void Lb3SumF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Replacing * with + does not invoke an event which never supposed to be invoked.

Comment: He is using wrong operator, How i know without Gui that which event is attached with which function here.
@MasoudKeshavarz

Comment: @MasoudKeshavarz As he mentioned this url of his output https://imgur.com/WffG3sZ , it seems his event's are working fine but he get wrong answer only of his '*' Operator instead of '+' operator.